# Convert a bunch of BMP files to JPEG on Linux

Tags: linux, conversion, jpeg, bmp

Someone sent me a bunch of BMP files and I need them in JPEG. I could convert them one by one using GIMP, but I'd rather do it all in one go. I have Ubuntu.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

You can use ImageMagick's mogrify tool

```
mogrify -format jpg *.bmp
```

Comment: Note that this answer works for Windows too, as ImageMagick is available to download for Windows as well.

Comment: It's `sudo apt install imagemagick` on Ubuntu and you can set the quality by adding `-quality 100`

Answer (score 22):

You are likely to have [ImageMagick](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ImageMagick) installed on Ubuntu.
That [can do](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php),

```
convert filename.bmp filename.jpg
```

---

update:

The [`mogrify`](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php) (answered by `hyperslug` and referred by `cjm`) is also a good option.

> Use the **mogrify** program to resize an image, blur, crop, despeckle, dither, draw on, flip, join, re-sample, and much more.
>   This tool is similiar to **convert** except that the original image file is overwritten
>   (unless you change the file suffix with the `-format` option) with any changes you request.

Comment: ImageMagick's mogrify command is better than convert for this, because it can be used easily with wildcards.  See hyperslug's answer.

Answer (score 9):

Let me do a little change to salmonmoose answer:

```
for i in `ls *.bmp`; do convert $i $i.jpg; done
```

The above works but generates files named "bmp.jpg". You can get .jpg files with this command:

```
for i in *.bmp; do convert ${i} ${i%bmp}jpg; done
```

See `man bash` for details of the `for` command. The `${i%bmp}` part means the string "${i}" without the "bmp" substring at the end.

There are other operations to transform the string in "${i}". "$i" is a shorthand for "${i}". The `ls *.bmp` part in salmonmoose answer means "execute `ls *.bmp`, then the for `i` part assigns each string separated by spaces to `i`". The same is achieved by `*.bmp` because it matches all file names in the directory.

There is a drawback with `for` - if the files in your directory have spaces in the name, for example "wedding picture 1.bmp", it will be assigned 3 times to the `i` var, performing these commands:

```
convert wedding wedding.jpg 
convert picture picture.jpg
convert 1.bmp  1.bmp.jpg
```

In my answer also the match "${i%bmp}" fails.

But there is a solution - you can use the `find` command instead. See `man find` for details. You should type something like the following (please check the syntax with the man page before trying it):

```
find -name *.bmp -type f -exec convert '{}' '{}'.jpg \;
```

(I am not very sure of the name part, and I have some doubt in the `-exec` part, see `man find` first)

If you want to join all the images in one .jpg file, you can concatenate them with other filter, as the one mentioned in the first answer.

Comment: This fails on files containing a space in the name so would be more robust if quoted i.e. `for i in *.bmp; do convert "${i}" "${i%bmp}jpg"; done`

Answer (score 1):

```
for i in `ls *.bmp`; do convert $i $i.jpg; done
```

Yes, this will make a bunch of files called filename.bmp.jpg but it'll do the job.

Comment: Useless use of `ls`.

Answer (score 1):

Convert .bmp to .jpg using Linux:

```
for ii in *bmp;do base=`echo $ii|cut -d"." -f1`; convert $ii $base.jpg;done
```

Results:

```
foo2.bmp becomes foo2.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Recursive using find and ImageMagick's mogrify:

```
find . -iname *.bmp -exec mogrify -format png "{}" \;
```

The bmp files will remain in place.